# SimpleXML storing data into array

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

I'm working on storing result of xml feed into database... I'm able to load file... but when I want to store data into array, it stores instead of value (`[title] = 'Klapka 120mm';`) this:

> [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Klapka 120mm )

Do you know, where might be problem?

Source code:

Here is part of one function:

```
$import_file = simplexml_load_file($this->input->post('import_url')); // load file from url
$affected_products = 0;
     foreach($import_file->SHOPITEM as $product) {
                    $affected_products += $this->import_product($product);
    }
```

Here is first part of function import_product:

```
public function import_product($product) 
{   
    /* save product data into array */
   $data = array(
            'title' => $product->PRODUCT,
            'content' => $product->DESCRIPTION,
            'price' => $product->PRICE,
            'price_vat' => $product->PRICE_VAT,
            'ean' => $product->EAN,
            'count' => $product->AVAILABILITY
        );
   die(print_r($data));
```

Thank you very much for your replies

Comment: `$data = array_map('strval', $data);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to cast the elements to strings, as all these elements are instances of SimpleXMLElement.

```
$data = array(
  'title'     => (string)$product->PRODUCT,
  'content'   => (string)$product->DESCRIPTION,
  'price'     => (string)$product->PRICE,
  'price_vat' => (string)$product->PRICE_VAT,
  'ean'       => (string)$product->EAN,
  'count'     => (string)$product->AVAILABILITY
);
```

For some of them a cast to an integer or a float may be of interest